# Android - manipulating visibility in some Expandible List's children

Tags: android, listview, visibility, children

In Android, I'm trying to manipulate some children rows of a Expandible List in the **getChildView()** function but the next code seems does not work properly:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
    boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View childRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buslinescheduleitem, null);
        if(childPosition%4==0) {
            int k = 0;
            TextView textView;
            while((childPosition+k) < getChildrenCount(groupPosition) && k < 4){
                textView= (TextView) childRow.findViewById(textViewIds[k]);
                textView.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition+k));
                k++;
            }
            childRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else { childRow.setVisibility(View.GONE); }
        return childRow;
}
```

Although some children rows have been modified with Visibility GONE and the views haven't been shown, the groupView has its "holes" where shouldn't (As if this rows would had Visibility with INVISIBLE value). Is it posible to hide some children rows when the Expandible List is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I've created ONLY a row for each four rows:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
    boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View childRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buslinescheduleitem, null);
        int k = 0;
        TextView textView;
        while(((childPosition*NUMBER_ROWS)+k) < getChildrenSize(groupPosition) && k < NUMBER_ROWS){
            textView= (TextView) childRow.findViewById(textViewIds[k]);
            textView.setText(getChild(groupPosition, (childPosition*NUMBER_ROWS)+k));
            k++;
        }
        while(k < NUMBER_ROWS){
            textView= (TextView) childRow.findViewById(textViewIds[k]);
            textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            k++;
        }
        return childRow;    
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(!isInverted) return (int) Math.ceil((float)busLine.getBusScheduleRound().get(groupPosition).getHours().size()/(float)NUMBER_ROWS);
    else return (int) Math.ceil((float)busLine.getBusScheduleReturn().get(groupPosition).getHours().size()/(float)NUMBER_ROWS);
}

public int getChildrenSize(int groupPosition){
    if(!isInverted) return busLine.getBusScheduleRound().get(groupPosition).getHours().size();
    else return busLine.getBusScheduleReturn().get(groupPosition).getHours().size();        
}
```

Nevertheless, I haven't achieved modifing the visibility.